# Swift: Can the type of an Element in an Array be discovered and used to specify the generic type argument?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

I have a protocol named `APIRequest` with an associated type named `ResponseType` and a decode function. This example is not complete, but I believe these are the only relevant parts for the question.

There's also a struct named `ArrayResponse` to represent when a network response returns as an array of `items` of different objects (depending on the specific `APIRequest`'s `ResponseType`, as well as `totalItems`.

```
protocol APIRequest {
    associatedtype ResponseType: Codable

    /// Decodes the request result into the ResponseType
    func decode(_: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType
}

struct ArrayResponse<T>: Codable where T: Codable {
    let items: [T]
    let totalItems: Int
}
```

Here's an example of a struct that adheres to the `APIRequest` protocol and specifies it's `ResponseType` as `Brand`, which is a `Codable` struct that represents brand data being returned from the server.

```
struct BrandRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = Brand
}
```

```
struct Brand: Codable {
    var brandID: Int
    var brandName: String?
}
```

The `BrandRequest` is used to fetch a single `Brand` from the server, but I can also fetch an array of `Brand`'s (represented by the `ArrayResponse` above, since Brand is one of many different types that all follow the same pattern), using `BrandsRequest`, which specifies it's `ResponseType` as an array of `Brand`s.

```
struct BrandsRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = [Brand]
}
```

Rather than providing a `decode` function in every struct that adheres to `APIRequest`, I've decided to make a default implementation in a protocol extension, since they all follow the same decoding.

Depending on whether the `ResponseType` is an array (such as `[Brand]`, or a single item, such as `Brand`, I use a different version of the `decode` function. This works well for the single item, but for the array of items, I'd like to look into the Array, discover the type of it's Elements, and use that to check if the `result.decoded()` is decoded as an `ArrayResponse<>` of that particular type.

So, for example, if I make a `BrandsRequest`, I'd like this top `decode` function which decodes the Array to return `(try result.decoded() as ArrayResponse<Brand>).items` with `Brand` being a different struct (e.g. `Product`, `Customer`, etc.) depending on the type of the Element in the array this function receives. This example has some non-compiling code as my attempt to get the `elementType` and use it as a generic argument, but of course that does not work. I also cannot simply pass `Codable` as the generic argument, since the compiler tells me: `Value of protocol type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is there a way to capture the Type of the Element in the Array to use in `ArrayResponse<insert type here>`?
2. Is there a better way to `decode` the network responses that return arrays of items that looks like `ArrayResponse` vs. single item response like `Brand`?

```
extension APIRequest where ResponseType == Array<Codable> {
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType {
        let elementType = type(of: ResponseType.Element.self)
        print(elementType)

        return (try result.decoded() as ArrayResponse<elementType>).items
    }
}

extension APIRequest {
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType {
        return try result.decoded() as ResponseType
    }
}
```

---

**Addendum:**
One other approach I thought of is to change `ArrayResponse<>` to use T as the array type, rather than the element type:

```
struct ArrayResponse<T>: Codable where T: Codable {
    let items: T
    let totalItems: Int
}
```

and then to simplify the array decode like so:

```
extension APIRequest where ResponseType == Array<Codable> {
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType {
        return (try result.decoded() as ArrayResponse<ResponseType>).items
    }
}
```

However, the compiler gives me these 2 errors:
`'ArrayResponse' requires that 'Decodable & Encodable' conform to 'Encodable'`
and
`Value of protocol type 'Decodable & Encodable' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

---

***Addendum 2:***
I can get everything working and compiling, if I add another associatedtype to `APIRequest` to define the type of Element within the array:

```
protocol APIRequest {
    associatedtype ResponseType: Codable
    associatedtype ElementType: Codable

    /// Decodes the request result into the ResponseType
    func decode(_: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType
}
```

and then change my array `decode` function to use `ElementType` instead of `Codable`:

```
extension APIRequest where ResponseType == Array<ElementType> {
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ResponseType {
        return (try result.decoded() as ArrayResponse<ResponseType>).items
    }
}
```

but then I have to supply the `ElementType` in each struct that conforms to `APIRequest`, including the single requests where it's redundant to `ResponseType` and not used. For the array requests, it's simply the value inside the array `ResponseType`, which also feels repetitive:

```
struct BrandRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = Brand
    typealias ElementType = Brand
}

struct BrandsRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = [Brand]
    typealias ElementType = Brand
}
```

The crux of my problem is that I'd like to discover the `Brand` type within the `[Brand]` array, and use it for the `ArrayResponse` decoding.

Comment: What is `.decoded()` and why do you expect it return an `ArrayResponse`? It would be helpful if you reduced this to a conceptual example

Comment: I don't understand why you need ArrayResponse at all. A Swift Array already conforms to Codable and you can compute the total number of items via the count property. Your life would be much simpler if you abandoned that type and used an array without a wrapper.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree The API returns 10 items at a time by default, and up to 100 if requested, but the total number of items that exist in may be larger, this is to support paging.

Comment: @NewDev `.decoded()` is a JSON decoder, relatively standard so I didn't include it's source since the question is already large. It works and does return a type that is an `ArrayResponse` when making a `BrandsRequest` or any other request for many items.

Comment: When you create a PAT (protocol w/ associated type), the key question is how it will be called, or what extensions will be applied to it, since it can't be stored in a variable or array. It's not clear what value APIRequest is providing to the caller. My strong suspicion is that this is misuse of protocols, and you really want a generic function instead (which would make most of these issues evaporate). What does the calling code look like that relies on APIRequest?

Comment: @RobNapier This version is a bit old and doesn't have the updates above, but will give you a better sense of how the `APIRequest` is structured and used. https://github.com/mailchimp/Mailchimp-SDK-iOS/tree/master/MailchimpSDK/MailchimpSDK/Core/Networking

`EventRequest` and `ContactRequest` are structs that adhere to `APIRequest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a misuse of protocols. PATs (protocols with associated types) are all about adding more features to existing types, and it's not clear this does that. Instead, I believe you have a generics problem.

As before, you have an `ArrayResponse`, because that's a special thing in your API:

```
struct ArrayResponse<Element: Codable>: Codable {
    let items: [Element]
    let totalItems: Int
}
```

Now, instead of a protocol, you need a generic struct:

```
struct Request<Response: Codable> {
    // You need some way to fetch this, so I'm going to assume there's an URLRequest
    // hiding in here.
    let urlRequest: URLRequest

    // Decode single values
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> Response {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: result.get())
    }

    // Decode Arrays. This would be nice to put in a constrained extension instead of here,
    // but that's not currently possible in Swift
    func decode(_ result: Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> ArrayResponse<Response> {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(ArrayResponse<Response>.self, from: result.get())
    }
}
```

And finally, you need a way to create "BrandRequest" (but really `Request<Brand>`):

```
struct Brand: Codable {
    var brandID: Int
    var brandName: String?
}

// You want "BrandRequest", but that's just a particular URLRequest for Request<Brand>.
// I'm going to make something up for the API:
extension Request where Response == Brand {
    init(brandName: String) {
        self.urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/brands/(\brandName)")!)
    }
}
```

That said, I'd probably adjust this and create different `Request` extensions that attach the correct decoder (element vs array) depending on the request. The current design, based on your protocol, forces the caller at decode time to decide if there are one or more elements, but that's known when the request is created. So I'd probably build Request more along these lines, and make `Response` explicitly `ArrayResponse`:

```
struct Request<Response: Codable> {
    // You need some way to fetch this, so I'm going to assume there's an URLRequest
    // hiding in here.
    let urlRequest: URLRequest
    let decoder: (Result<Data, APIError>) throws -> Response
}
```

(and then assign the appropriate decoder in the `init`)

---

Looking at the code you linked, yeah, that's a pretty good example of using protocols to try to recreate class inheritance. The APIRequest extension is all about creating default implementations, rather than applying generic algorithms, and that usually suggests an "inherit and override" OOP mindset. Rather than a bunch of individual structs that conform to APIRequest, I would think this would work better as a single APIRequest generic struct (as described above).

But you can still get there without rewriting all the original code. For example, you can make a generic "array" mapping:

```
struct ArrayRequest<Element: Codable>: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = [Element]
    typealias ElementType = Element
}

typealias BrandsRequest = ArrayRequest<Brand>
```

And of course you could push that up a layer:

```
struct ElementRequest<Element: Codable>: APIRequest {
    typealias ResponseType = Element
    typealias ElementType = Element
}

typealias BrandRequest = ElementRequest<Brand>
```

And all your existing APIRequest stuff still works, but your syntax can be a lot simpler (and there's no actual requirement to create the typealiases; `ElementRequest<Brand>` is probably fine on its own).

---

Extending some of this based on your comment, you want to add an `apiPath`, and I take it you're trying to figure out where to put that information. That fits perfectly in my Request type. Each `init` is responsible for creating an URLRequest. Any way it wants to do that is fine.

Simplifying things to the basics:

```
struct Brand: Codable {
    var brandID: Int
    var brandName: String?
}

struct Request<Response: Codable> {
    let urlRequest: URLRequest
    let parser: (Data) throws -> Response
}

extension Request where Response == Brand {
    init(brandName: String) {
        self.init(
            urlRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/brands/\(brandName)")!),
            parser: { try JSONDecoder().decode(Brand.self, from: $0) }
        )
    }
}
```

But now we want to add User:

```
struct User: Codable {}

extension Request where Response == User {
    init(userName: String) {
        self.init(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/users/\(userName)")!),
                  parser: { try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: $0) }
        )
    }
}
```

That's almost identical. So identical that I cut-and-pasted it. And that tells me that it is *now* time to pull out reusable code (because I'm getting rid of a real duplication, not just inserting abstraction layers).

```
extension Request {
    init(domain: String, id: String) {
        self.init(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/\(domain)/\(id)")!),
                  parser: { try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: $0) }
        )
    }
}

extension Request where Response == Brand {
    init(brandName: String) {
        self.init(domain: "brands", id: brandName)
    }
}

extension Request where Response == User {
    init(userName: String) {
        self.init(domain: "users", id: userName)
    }
}
```

But what about ArrayResponse?

```
extension Request {
    init<Element: Codable>(domain: String) where Response == ArrayResponse<Element> {
        self.init(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1/\(domain)")!),
                  parser: { try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: $0) }
        )
    }
}
```

Arg! Duplication again! Well, then fix that problem, and putting it all together:

```
extension Request {
    static var baseURL: URL { URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v1")! }

    init(path: String) {
        self.init(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Request.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)),
                  parser: { try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: $0) })
    }

    init(domain: String, id: String) {
        self.init(path: "\(domain)/\(id)")
    }

    init<Element: Codable>(domain: String) where Response == ArrayResponse<Element> {
        self.init(path: domain)
    }
}

extension Request where Response == Brand {
    init(brandName: String) {
        self.init(domain: "brands", id: brandName)
    }
}

extension Request where Response == User {
    init(userName: String) {
        self.init(domain: "users", id: userName)
    }
}
```

Now this is just one of many ways to approach it. Instead of Request extension for each type, it might be nicer to have a Fetchable protocol, and put the domain there:

```
protocol Fetchable: Codable {
    static var domain: String { get }
}
```

Then you can hang the information on the model types like:

```
extension User: Fetchable {
    static let domain = "users"
}

extension ArrayResponse: Fetchable where T: Fetchable {
    static var domain: String { T.domain }
}

extension Request where Response: Fetchable {
    init(id: String) {
        self.init(domain: Response.domain, id: id)
    }

    init<Element: Fetchable>() where Response == ArrayResponse<Element> {
        self.init(domain: Response.domain)
    }
}
```

Notice that these aren't mutually exclusive. You can have both approaches at the same time because doing it this way composes. Different abstraction choices don't have to interfere with each other.

If you did that, you'd start to move towards the design from my [Generic Swift talk](https://youtu.be/DXwJg0QTlZE), which is just another way to do it. That talk is about an approach to designing generic code, not a specific implementation choice.

And all without needing associated types. The way you know an associated type probably makes sense is that different conforming types implement the protocol requirements differently. For example, Array's implementation of the subscript requirement is very different than Repeated's implementation and LazySequence's implementation. If every implementation of the protocol requirements would be structurally identical, then you're probably looking at a generic struct (or possibly a class), not a protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're right about me trying to fit OOP into PAT. My question may not have been detailed enough (tried to strike a balance of conceptual & concrete, with a decent length) and the MC SDK I linked above has requests where the `apiPath` is a string literal, which is easy enough to fit into the suggested pattern with an extension and custom init, but most of my calls to fetch a single object from the API require an identifier in the `apiPath`, e.g. `apiPath = "brand/\(brandID)`. I'm trying to figure out how to handle that with the above approach.

Comment: Thank you, this approach and your talk were helpful. I think this will keep the call site simplicity I was aiming for and make adding 50+ models/endpoints quick. Thoughts on how the generic `Request` type fits in with your `Transport` fetch? POST requests that take Codable objects as the `httpBody`? Would it make sense to decode like you do in `parser` but have a `completion` block like `let completion: (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void`? Our network errors are used (see `APIError`), so decoding is a bit more complex as in the implementations of `requestComplete` in the MC SDK linked above.

Comment: I think I have something like what you're describing here: https://robnapier.net/at-your-request (this is the last part of a series that covers the same ground as that talk). The goal is to create pluggable stages. You want something that generates an URLRequest. You want something that transforms an `URLRequest` into a `Result<Data, Error>`, and you want something that transforms a `Result<Data, Error>` into a `Result<Response, APIError>`. Transport is just about making the second piece of that pluggable.

Comment: A key point is that it doesn't matter *how* you generate an URLRequest for this system. So for your "POST requests that take Codable objects as the httpBody," that just means you want function that accepts an URL and a Codable and generates an URLRequest. That's not a type or an architecture; that's just a function. It could even be a static or free function. You may find it's convenient to put it as a method inside a type (a "client" or whatever) that knows things like the baseURL. But any approach can plug into the rest of the system. It really can be whatever is convenient.

Comment: BTW, if you decide to switch to Combine, the exact same approach works. I'm building a Combine system like this right now. I have this "NetworkService" that has methods like `func getAccount(credentials: Credentials) -> AnyPublisher<AccountInfo, Error>`. It's just a function that turns a set of Credentials into an Account asynchronously. No different than a completion handler. Underneath it uses a Transport that turns URLRequests into Data.